# Hashset not adding a duplicate, but returning true for Add()

Tags: c#

(edit) more info. First notice "new virtual". This class inherits a base class which is supposed to be a generic parent-aware class that can be created with any ICollection type. Here's the descriptor, basically:

```
public abstract class ParentAwareCollection<TObject, TParent, TInnerList> :
 ICollection<TObject>, ICollection, IParentProvider<TParent>
    where TObject : IParentProvider<TParent>
    where TInnerList : ICollection<TObject>, new()
{
        protected TInnerList InnerList = new TInnerList();
...
}
```

This class:

```
 public class ParentAwareHashset<TObject, TParent> : 
   ParentAwareCollection<TObject, TParent, HashSet<TObject>>, ISet<TObject>, 
   ICollection  where TObject : IParentProvider<TParent>
    {
        public ParentAwareHashset(TParent parent)
            : base(parent)
```

IParentProvider just requires that a "ParentCollection" object be present.

In debugging, the overridden (void) Add method in `ParentAwareCollection` is never called. So I don't think that the "new" is the problem.

Also, here's something that I also don't understand. Here's the descriptor for an actual HashSet:

```
public class HashSet<T> : ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, 
ISet<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
...
        public bool Add(T item);
}
```

Notice that in implements ICollection just like mine. That is what led me to believe that this was OK to do. However unlike mine, the framework HashSet does not use a `new` descriptor for its Add() method, but that's required because `ICollection<T>` implements `void Add(T item)`. Perhaps they just omitted it?

Original question:

I have a collection class that uses a `HashSet<T>` to store its objects. The objects of type T override `GetHashCode()`, in which they make sure that certain required information is present that is used to produce the hash code. I am not sure if this is important.

What happens is that when I do an Add(T) to the HashSet, it does not add the object, but returns true. If I debug and then in the immediate window try to add it again, it returns false, like it's supposed to. The method looks like this:

```
public new virtual bool Add(TObject item)
{
    // Must add parent first, since it may be used in the hash code
    // InnerList is a HashSet<T>

    if (InnerList.Any(existing=>item.GetHashCode()==existing.GetHashCode())) {
        return(false);
    } else {
        if (InnerList.Add(item))
        {
            return(true);
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I added the first condition to make my code actually work. It works as expected with this there. However, I can't understand why I would have to do this, and I can think of no reason, ever, why a HashSet would return "true" for Add() without adding anything. Even if my GetHashCode override is messed up, it should either add it and return true, or not and return false. Any thoughts?

Here's what I observed while debugging:

Breaking before InnerList.Add():

```
?InnerList.Count
1
?item.GetHashCode()
-1629834529
?InnerList.ElementAt(0).GetHashCode()
-1629834529
```

Step over the InnerList.Add(), which returns true:

```
?InnerList.Count
1
?InnerList.Add(item)
false
```

Wtf? This is .net 4.0 framework.

Comment: Maybe you could post a 'ready-to-run'-codesample that allows to reproduce this problem? Otherwise it is hard to guess where the problem is...

Comment: What is the definition of TObject?  How can we reproduce it?

Comment: There's a lot of code... I'll put the base class up. Ssee my edit. I don't totally understand it, though, because I am calling InnerList.Add directly so I don't get why the base class add would ever get called, and it has no return anyway, going to try a couple things...

Comment: Note that you should not assume uniqueness of the hash code. You should override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in tandem. `GetHashCode` is the first item of verification, so to speak. If they don't match, the assumption is `Equals` will also be false. But since `GetHashCode` does not guarantee uniqueness, matching hash codes *do not mean Equals is true*. In short, the HashSet will check the hash code first, check `Equals` if appropriate, and you shouldn't reject an `Add` simply based on a hash code match, either.

Comment: @Anthony - I wonder if that has something to do with this? I haven't done that, I'll add that. But nonethless, I can't understand why it would return true for add, without actually adding something..

Comment: I must be missing something. It looks to me from what you posted like `Add` is returning `false`.

Comment: Dan Tao - it returned false when I tried to add it a 2nd time in the immediate window. That 2nd block of code in the immediate window is after stepping through the actual InnerList.Add in the code, which returns true, yet the list count remained 1.

Comment: @jamietre: Gotcha. You're not by any chance calling this method from multiple threads, are you?

Comment: Nope. See my answer, think I figured it out, has to do with the multiple inheritances and base classes, though still don't totally understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. This is a very insidious little thing. So the whole point of this setup is so that I can have collection classes that have a "Parent", and when you add items to the collection, they are automatically assigned that Parent. (This Parent is not simply the class itself, it's another object).

Here is the problem:

```
        CsmResourceHashSet resources = new CsmResourceHashSet(Context);
        resources.AddFrom(Context.ScriptResources
            .Where(item=>item.Enabled));
```

`CsmResourceHashSet` is a `ParentAwareHashset`. Extension method AddFrom:

```
public static void AddFrom<T>(this ICollection<T> destList, IEnumerable<T> sourceList)
{
    foreach (T obj in sourceList)
    {
        destList.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

so it's apparently using the `ICollection` implementation to perform the Add. The `void Add` method of the base `ParentAwareCollection` is being used.

I guess it is casting my object to the base class when it uses this, even though I have a '`new Add`. It seems weird to me that when you override a method with new, that an instance of that object could still have it's base method operated on externally.

@Anthony Pegram's comment actually enabled me to find the solution. So what was happening is that the void Add() was being called, which consequently called the actual derived InnerList Add(), which was indeed returning false, but that value was never getting back to code that needed to know about it.

The effect was that the HashSet actually had the correct contents, but Parent didn't get set for the one that got rejected from the HashSet. So this made the code work almost all the time... except when it mattered that the code didn't know something had been rejected. But without the "Equals" check, also, I was permitting duplicates of things that I shouldn't have been.

Solution was to add another ExtensionMethod for ISet<>

```
public static void AddFrom<T>(this ISet<T> destList, IEnumerable<T> sourceList)
{
    foreach (T obj in sourceList)
    {
        destList.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Once I did that, it works. Well, actually it didn't work, but it revealed a couple crazy little bugs that mostly didn't manifest themselves, but all my exceptions started blowing up everywhere and it took no time to fix them all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Add` code is wrong:

```
public new virtual bool Add(TObject item)
{
    // Must add parent first, since it may be used in the hash code
    // InnerList is a HashSet<T>

    if (InnerList.Any(existing=>item.GetHashCode()==existing.GetHashCode())) {
        return(false);
    } else {
        if (InnerList.Add(item))
        {
            return(true);
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Two different items can have the same hash code! Your function should look like this:

```
public new virtual bool Add(TObject item)
{
    return InnerList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: As I said, I added that first check because it was not working with just InnerList.Add(). The problem is that HashSet.Add() is adding returning true even though it doesn't add the item. I do realize I need to check Equals as well but that would only result in false negatives, not the problem I am having.

Comment: A quick look at `HashSet<T>.Add` with reflector verifies that's not possible. Either a different thread removes the item before your check, or the debugger is playing tricks with you - try printing

Comment: Yeah it's not HashSet's fault, but there is something a bit baffling at play here, see my answer.