# Correct way to Inherit multiple interfaces with same methods but different signatures?

Tags: c#, interface

After pulling my hair out over [this debacle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796221/hashset-not-adding-a-duplicate-but-returning-true-for-add/4797068#4797068) I was hoping an expert could tell me if this is correct.

I have these classes:

```
public class ParentAwareHashset<TObject, TParent> : 
        ParentAwareCollection<TObject,TParent, HashSet<TObject>>,
        ICollection<TObject>, ISet<TObject>  
        where TObject : IParentProvider<TParent>

public abstract class ParentAwareCollection<TObject, TParent, TInnerList> :
ICollection<TObject>,  IParentProvider<TParent>
        where TObject : IParentProvider<TParent>
        where TInnerList : ICollection<TObject>, new()
```

The base class implements `void Add` for `ICollection<T>`. In my inherited class, I got into trouble by implementing `public new bool Add(TObject item)` which is the only way to implement the `bool Add` ISet method, since the signature doesn't match the underlying `void Add` method. So what happend was, I happened to do something to it with a method that only had an implementation for `ICollection`, the base class `Add` method was being used.

I think I figured out how to do this right... but I am still not sure I will avoid any unexpected behavior, so was hoping some guru could confirm or deny this approach.

```
    bool ISet<TObject>.Add(TObject item) 
    {
        return(Add(item));
    }
    void ICollection<TObject>.Add(TObject item)
    {  
        throw new Exception(@"You probably didn't mean for this to happen, you're
          using a method that doesn't have an ISet implementation.");
    }
    public new virtual bool Add(TObject item)
    {
        // my actual add code
    }
```

Can someone tell me if an object of type ParentAwareHashset would be guaranteed to always run the "new" method, or fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the explicitly implemented interface methods call the correct method rather than throwing an exception:

```
bool ISet<TObject>.Add(TObject item) 
{
    return(Add(item));
}
void ICollection<TObject>.Add(TObject item)
{  
    **return(Add(item))**;
}
public new virtual bool Add(TObject item)
{
    // my actual add code
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was worried about the consequences of not handling the return value for the add. But I guess, if I'm using an ICollection method, then by definition I don't care what the return is, as long as my own implementation of Add is being used. Thanks.

Comment: Oh and technically that doesn't work (since can't return bool to a void)... but `Add(item); return;` does.

Comment: Yes, true, I didn't compile the sample ... but it got the point across :-)